# The game object of type "healthscript" has already been destroyed but you are trying to access it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im new to unity. Ive made a preferb of enemy. I have made a script where I could kill them by jumping over. But when I jump over a random enemy only one is getting killed than the message occurs. here is the code I used in my player

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) 
{
    aipatrol enemy = collision.collider.GetComponent<aipatrol>();

    if (enemy != null)
    {
        foreach (ContactPoint2D point in collision.contacts)
        {
            Debug.Log(point.normal);
            Debug.DrawLine(point.point,point.point + point.normal,Color.red,10);

            if (point.normal.y >= 0.9f)
            {
                healthscipt.Takedamage(10);
            }
            else
            {
                hurt();
            }  
        }
    }
```

here is the code I used in enemy

```
public void Takedamage(float damage)
{
    hp -= damage;

    if(hp <= 0f )
    {
        Die();
    }
}

void Die ()
{
    if(diepeffect != null)
    {
        Instantiate (diepeffect,transform.position,Quaternion.identity);
    }

    float spawnrate = Random.Range(0,100f);

    if (spawnrate <= chancetospawnammo)
    {
        Instantiate(ammodrop,transform.position,Quaternion.identity);
    }

    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

I'm new . So I'm only trying to learn by following various youtube videos. Need help.

Comment: What is the healthscript variable in your player class?

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing `healtscript` in a `foreach` loop where you do

```c#
...
if (point.normal.y >= 0.9f)
{
    healthscipt.Takedamage(10);
}
```

which does

```c#
...
if(hp <= 0f )
{
    Die();
}
```

which finally destroys that object in

```c#
...
Destroy(gameObject);
```

So if you now get to the next iteration of your loop that object is already destroyed!

---

You could skip in that case using

```c#
foreach (ContactPoint2D point in collision.contacts)
{
    Debug.Log(point.normal);
    Debug.DrawLine(point.point,point.point + point.normal,Color.red,10);
    if (point.normal.y >= 0.9f)
    {
        // If healthscipt was already destroyed -> nothing to do
        if(!healthscipt) continue;

        healthscipt.Takedamage(10);
    }
    else
    {
        hurt();
    }  
}
```

or - assuming the same would apply also to the `hurt` method - you could move it up

```c#
foreach (ContactPoint2D point in collision.contacts)
{
    // If healthscipt was already destroyed -> nothing to do
    if(!healthscipt) continue;

    Debug.Log(point.normal);
    Debug.DrawLine(point.point,point.point + point.normal,Color.red,10);
    if (point.normal.y >= 0.9f)
    {
        healthscipt.Takedamage(10);
    }
    else
    {
        hurt();
    }  
}
```

---

Then from the comments you say you are using

```c#
healtScript = FindObjectOfType<healthscript>();
```

This will always be the same value for all instances namely the first active instance in your Scene!

You probably would rather use

```c#
// Get the healthScript of the enemy you collide with
var healthScript = enemy.GetComponent<healthscript>();

foreach (ContactPoint2D point in collision.contacts)
{
    // If healthscipt was already destroyed -> nothing to do
    if(!healthscipt) continue;

    Debug.Log(point.normal);
    Debug.DrawLine(point.point,point.point + point.normal,Color.red,10);
    if (point.normal.y >= 0.9f)
    {
        healthscipt.Takedamage(10);
    }
    else
    {
        hurt();
    }  
}
```

Comment: the error doesnt pop up anymore but everytime I jump on a random enemy one significant enemy of the same preferb is getting killed . and then I cant kill no other neither they can damage me. why is this happening? need help ;-;

Comment: @ZIhan This brings us back to the question in the comments: how exactly is `healthScript` initialized?

Comment: okay my whole code is surpassing word limit, but my scipt doesnt contain that much. in the start method hp is equaled to maxhp. the update method is empty. the rest of the scirpt is already in the lower description.

Comment: @ZIhan this still doesn't clear how the value `healthScript` is assigned exactly and which reference it is holding ... in your first script there would be somewhere a line starting with `healthscript = ...`

Comment: there is a line in the start method; healthscipt = FindobjectTypeof<healthscipt>(). did u mean this?

Comment: Well yes! That is exactly your issue! `FindobjectTypeof<healthscipt>()` will find the first active instance of `healthscript` in your scene. => It will always find the same one. You should rather use e.g. `GetComponent<healtScript>()` if it is attached to the same object or you might rather want to get it inside of the collision doing `var healthScript = enemy.GetComponent<healthscript>();` to get the component of the object you collide with

Comment: I have deleted the healthscipt and then took every code to aipatrol. Than it started working as there was already a getcomponent metod used there.Thanks for the help man.